# puppet: file, template and variables

Tags: puppet, template

I'm trying to create a file based on templates, but I'm getting an error that the template(s) cannot be found.

My directory setup is /etc/puppet/modules//templates/

Under templates, if have a directory for each host, plus a common template.  Under the host directory I have a template specific to that host.

## /server/puppet/modules//manifests/init.pp

class  {

```
file { "/tmp/<file>":
    ensure  => present,
    content => template('<module>/${hostname}/default.erb', '<module>/common.erb'),
    audit   => content,
    notify  => File["/tmp/<file2>"],
}

file { "/tmp/<file2>":
    ensure => present,
    source => "/tmp/file",
    audit   => content,
}
```

}

when I run the puppet agent, I get the error on the content option of the first file statement.  I don't know if the template function needs the templates directly under the template directory or if it's not interpreting the hostname variable correctly.

Comment: Please post the error you're getting.

Comment: And if you can help it, use actual values rather than syntactically incorrect placeholders like `<file>` and `<module>`, because this distracts from the real issue.

Comment: If you run puppet in debug mode (`-d`), you'll get lots of diagnostic output and you'll probably be able to see if `$hostname` is expanding as you expect.

Comment: Variables aren't parsed inside single quotes. Use double quotes when you need to interpolate $variables.

Comment: Thanks czervik.  The double quotes took care of the issue.  Another example of "don't follow the documentation too closely".

Comment: @czervik, you mith want add your comment as an answer, since it seems to have solved Todd's issue.

Answer (score 4):

Variables aren't parsed inside single quotes. Use double quotes when you need to interpolate $variables.

https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/3.8/lang_datatypes.html#strings